# How do I set the correct time zone on my Nexus 4?

Tags: nexus-4, clock, time-zones

I just purchased a Nexus 4.

I'm perplexed, however, in that it thinks that I am in the Central timezone when I'm actually in the Eastern timezone.

The Clock application that came with the phone has a "Home Timezone" option. This only puts a secondary clock on the clock app when I'm outside of my Home Timezone, which is always the case, because the phone thinks I'm on the Central timezone.

How do I set my phone to the correct timezone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be under your system settings (the Settings "app"), in the "Date & Time" subsection (which is near the bottom). Uncheck the "Automatic time zone" option and then select the correct one manually:

[image]

Comment: Right on! My sim card was not a micro sim, so I'm currently running without a network-provided time zone. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also follow the advice in [How do I change the time zone (which is disabled) in Honeycomb on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9163/how-do-i-change-the-time-zone-which-is-disabled-in-honeycomb-on-a-samsung-gala) which is to use free application [Timezone Changer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.futurek.android.tzc). There is also [Timezone Fixer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.force.timezonefixer), which updates timezone files (needs ROOT access).